# Seperate string by recognizing first digit with regex

Tags: regex

I'm using `([^\d]+)\s?(.+)` for dividing a string by taking the first digit that appears inside the string.

Exp.: `Test123` --> Group1: `Test`, Group2: `123` # that works

but

Exp.: `Test` --> Group1: `Tes`, Group2: `t` # I expect: Group1: `Test`, Group 2: `[empty]`

How to edit the regex, so it fits my expcetation?

Comment: If you need to match up to the first digit if there is one, use [`^(.*?)\s*(\d.*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/jrBhVS/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thx, it did work.

Comment: Group 2 can't be empty. It matches `(.+)`, which matches at least 1 character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to match up to the first digit if there is one, you may use

```
^(.*?)\s*(\d.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jrBhVS/2)

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (since `*?` is a lazy quantifier)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d.*)?` - Group 2: an optional capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a digit and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possilbe (`*` is a greedy quantifier)
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex almost works

**Problem**: The problem lies in your second capturing group `(.+)` this means **at least one** of any character. It will grab the 't' at the end of test in order to make a match, since it must have at least one character in it.

**Solution**: replace your second capturing group with `(.*)` this means at least zero of any character. (ie): it does not need to have any characters in it to make a match and it will grab any number of characters after 'Test'

here is your new working regex code:

```
([^\d]+)\s?(.*)
```

Comment: Note that `([^\d]+)\s?(.*)` will yield the same result as `([^\d]+)(.*)`, the `\s?` will never match any text since `[^\d]+` is greedy and also matches whitespace. You may use `(\D*?)\s?(.*)` if you want to avoid it (and make it a bit shorter). And `\s*` seems better since it may match 0 or more whitespaces (although we do not know the exact requirements here).

Comment: good optimisation. Yes your regex would work better for most cases, but I wanted to keep my answer as close to the original answer as possible since we don't know the context of the question